# Cannot Connect to an EC2 PostgreSQL Server from a Docker Container running in an AWS EKS Cluster Node

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, pyodbc

We have a PostgreSQL database running into an AWS EC2 instance. Our target is connecting to this database from a Docker container running into an EC2 node which is running inside an AWS EKS cluster. We use Python (`pyodbc`) to connect to the database.

We get this error:

```bash
2023-02-23T15:03:49.532858159Z     return pyodbc.connect(connection_str)
2023-02-23T15:03:49.532902079Z pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] could not connect to server: Network is unreachable\n\tIs the server running on host "****" and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?\ncould not connect to server: Network is unreachable\n\tIs the server running on host "5432" (0.0.21.56) and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?\n (101) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

We accessed the EKS EC2 node using Putty. When we run the same Python code for connecting to the database, the connection is successful.

We believe the Docker container has a connectivity issue. But we cannot figure out the issue.

This is the `docker-compose.yaml` file used when building the Docker image.

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  dev:
    image: dbimage
    container_name: dbimage
    build:
      context: .
      target: dbimage
      args:
         - BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1
         - BUILD_DATE
         - GITREF
    networks:
      - cloud-network
    volumes:
        - .:/app
networks:
  cloud-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved by adding the `--network host` option in the `docker run` command.